# React Native Text custom ellipsis

Tags: python, react-native, ellipsis

I'm currently using React Native's Text component like this

```
<Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">Some long texts...</Text>
```

This renders texts like this

```
First line
Second line…
```

I'd like to use different ellipsis, for example,
Instead of

```
End of a long line...
```

It would be

```
End of a long line ...More
```

Currently, possible solutions would be:

1. Count the number of characters and cut the string then concatenate custom ellipsis.

Problem: Font's width differs per character.

2. Use ellipsizeMode="clip" and create absolutely positioned View with a custom ellipsis.

Problem: Can't programmatically tell when the Text is clipped.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Will it be a solution to simply put another Text component after the truncated one, and inline it, with the word "more" written it ?

Comment: @MaieonBrix That sounds like a better version of my second solution. But how can I tell when the text is long enough to be clipped?

Comment: You could do some "maths", or much more simpler just chose a random characters number that you know will be the limit for the smaller device and just apply it. It doesn't have to be perfect and I would add that it's not hat big of deal if the truncated text is really small (I've seen truncated text hiding just 2 words)